# Angular 2: Getting undefined when return data from service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm using service to make http call and then return the response back to component where I get "undefined" when I console it. I have set timeout to make sure that the http request gets completed before console prints it but without any luck. I'm new to Angular 2, would really appreciate if someone could help me out.
    My serivce code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class LoginService {    

      rootUrl = 'https://dev-510009.oktapreview.com/'
      constructor(public _http: HttpClient){

      }
      primaryVerify1(userData) {
        let data = {
          "username": userData.username,
          "password": userData.pass,
          "options": {
            "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": true,
            "warnBeforePasswordExpired": true
          } 
        };
       this._http.post(this.rootUrl + "api/v1/authn", data, {
         headers: {
           'Content-type': 'application/json'
         }
       }).subscribe(response => {
         if(response.status == 'SUCCESS'){
          let primaryverifydata = response
           console.log("primaryverifydata", primaryverifydata)
           let data1 = {
              "factorType": "token:software:totp",
              "provider": "GOOGLE"
           }
           this._http.post(this.rootUrl + "api/v1/users/"+ primaryverifydata._embedded.user.id + "/factors", data1,
           {
             headers: {
               'Content-type': "application/json",
               'Authorization' :'SSWS 00e1Wq_tDwvikJt2ZufC0DgW58JX61R6BEQriGsvtl',
               'Accept': "application/json"
             }
           }).subscribe(response => {
             console.log(response)
             let enrollResponse = response;
             if(response.status = 'PENDING_ACTIVATION'){
               window.open(enrollResponse._embedded.activation._links.qrcode.href, '_blank')
               return response;
             }

           })
         }
       })
      }


}
```

My component code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { LoginService } from '../login-service.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
         providers: [LoginService],
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
         userData: object;
      pass: any;
        enrollResponse: object;
    constructor(private loginservice: LoginService) {
        this.userData = {};
        this.pass = "";
        this.enrollResponse = {}
       }
        ngOnInit(){
          /*  this.enrollResponse = this.loginservice.primaryVerify;
            console.log(" this.enrollResponse",  this.enrollResponse)*/
        }
        primaryVerify(){
            let some = this.loginservice.primaryVerify1(this.userData);
            setTimeout(() => {
                 console.log("this.enrollResponse", some)
            },5000)

        }
    }
Kindly note: primaryVerify() gets fired when user clicks on submit button.
```

Comment: Can you share your code on stackbliz?

Comment: `primaryVerify1` returns **nothing**. Besides, it's `async`, hence you should either wrap a callback, or return either a `Promise`, either an `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

primaryVerify1 does not return anything, so `undefined` is expected.

What you should do is using a callback or a Promise. Something along the lines of:

```
primaryVerify1(userData, callback) {
  ...
         let enrollResponse = response;
         if(response.status = 'PENDING_ACTIVATION'){
           window.open(enrollResponse._embedded.activation._links.qrcode.href, '_blank')
           callback(response);
         }
```

and use it like that:

```
let some = this.loginservice.primaryVerify1(this.userData, function(res) {
  console.log("this.enrollResponse", res);
});
```

Of course this does not handle errors very well (you may want to return early at each error possibility), but it gives you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) in your service `primaryVerify1()` since you are calling an http requests one after another. That will kill the previous observable.
2. Do not subscribe in your service, instead subscribe in your component and just [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) the results from service (i.e return resp from service). Make note of 3 return key words in the below code.
3. `setTimeout()` not required in component, instead subscribe to `primaryVerify1()`

Service code :

```
primaryVerify1(userData) {
        ...........
       return this._http.post(this.rootUrl + "api/v1/authn", data, {
         headers: {
           'Content-type': 'application/json'
         }
       }).pipe(switchMap(response => {
         if(response.status == 'SUCCESS'){
          ...............
           return this._http.post(this.rootUrl + "api/v1/users/"+ primaryverifydata._embedded.user.id + "/factors", data1,
           {
             headers: {
               'Content-type': "application/json",
               'Authorization' :'SSWS 00e1Wq_tDwvikJt2ZufC0DgW58JX61R6BEQriGsvtl',
               'Accept': "application/json"
             }
           }).pipe(map(response => {
             ...........
               return response;
             }))

           })
         }
       }))
    }
```

component

```
primaryVerify(){
     let some = this.loginservice.primaryVerify1(this.userData).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```